# Adding a collection to multiple axis?

Tags: matplotlib

I am trying to add a BrokenBarHCollection to multiple axis on my figure, as follows:

```
barcollection = collections.BrokenBarHCollection(...
ax1 = plt.subplot(211)
ax1.add_collection(barcollection)
ax2 = plt.subplot(212)
ax2.add_collection(barcollection)
plt.show()
```

As is, the figure only shows the collection in the second subplot. If I comment the ax2.add line out, it shows the collection only in the first subplot. Declaring the barcollection again between lines 3 and 4 makes it show up in both subplots. Why is this happening?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is because the `matplotlib` objects know what plot they are attached to and will not attach to more than one.

If you use the [copy module](http://docs.python.org/2/library/copy.html) to make a shallow copy, then you can re-use most of the data structure across multiple axes.

```
import copy
bc2 = copy.copy(barcollection)
ax2.add_collection(bc2)
```

There was another question about this recently, but I am having trouble finding it.