# Copying contours from one axes instance to another

Tags: python, matplotlib

I have a situation where I am producing upwards of 20 different images using matplotlib.  This is done many many times.  Each of the 20 images has the same set of contours in the background.  In order to reduce the processing time, it would be useful to be able to copy the result of `countourf()` from one `Axes` instance to another.  In order to do this, I have tried this:

```
#!/bin/env python

import os
import numpy as np
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt

def copycontours():
    #Create figures
    fig1 = plt.figure()
    fig2 = plt.figure()
    fig3 = plt.figure()

    #Create axes
    ax1 = fig1.add_axes((0.05,0.05,0.90,0.90))
    ax2 = fig2.add_axes((0.05,0.05,0.90,0.90))
    ax3 = fig3.add_axes((0.05,0.05,0.90,0.90))

    #Create random data
    data = np.random.normal(25, size=(25,25))

    #Add contours to first axes instance and save image
    contours = ax1.contourf(data)
    fig1.savefig('test.png')

    #Add contours to second axes instance from first axes instance
    for collection in ax1.collections:
        ax2.add_collection(collection)
    fig2.savefig('test2.png')

    #Add contours to third axes instance from 
    for collection in contours.collections:
        ax3.add_collection(collection)
    fig3.savefig('test3.png')

    os.system('display test.png &')
    os.system('display test2.png &')
    os.system('display test3.png &')

if __name__ == '__main__':
    copycontours()
```

The first figure (test.png) comes out looking correct.  The axes range from 0 to 25 and the full domain is filled.

[image: test1.png]

The other two (test2.png, test3.png) come out differently.  Their axes range from 0 to 1 and the contour region only fills the area from 0.0 to approximately 7.9.

[image: test2.png]

Resetting the axis limits via `ax2.set_xlim(0,25)` and `ax2.set_xlim(0,25)` changes the axis ranges, but does not fix the larger problem.

[image: test3.png]

Does anyone have a thought on how to fix this problem or another method for reusing the results of `contourf()` in a different way?

Comment: I suspect the answer is going to be something like this:  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13299294/adding-a-collection-to-multiple-axis/13301231#13301231 , however getting the collections from contour without the initial axes mixed up in them seems to be difficult.

Comment: Huh, that's interesting.  It seems odd to me that a matplotlib object would need to retain information about what axes instance it is attached to, but I haven't ever really looked at the internals of matplotlib.  I'll have to dig in a bit and see if I can figure out the reason.

Comment: It is part of the rather complicated rendering stack

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A sideways method of dealing with this is to re-use the axes that has the contour (as it looks like you are saving every figure and not looking at this interactively).

```
ax = fig.add_axes()
ax.contourf(..)
keep_lst = ax.get_children()[:] # state of the figure before adding anything extra

for plot_pram in conditions:
    # your plotting code

    fig.savefig()

    cur_children = ax.get_children()[:]
    # all the extra stuff you just plotted on it
    for a in cur_children:
        if a not in keep_lst:
            # if the artist isn't part of the initial set up, remove it
            a.remove()
```

Comment: Ah, that's an interesting way to handle it.  I hadn't thought to use `get_children()` like that.  The other method that I just worked up for this is to add a second set of axes with `axis_bgcolor=[0,0,0,0]`, plot what I want on it, then call `fig.delaxes(second_axes)`.  Rinse, repeat.